# Rails 6 Cascading Select List

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails

In Rails 6, I want the profiles/_form to have two dropdown lists, country and city. When I pick a value from country this is supposed to change the city choices. I want this to happen without 
refreshing the page. My solution is below, and it kind of works for the new action, but it doesn't work for the edit action. Is this the right approach or am I totally missing the idiomatic rails 6 solution?

A route to return the option tags for the city select box:

```
# config/routes.rb
get 'cities_by_country/:id', to: 'profiles#cities_by_country'
```

The action that runs

```
# profiles_controller
  def cities_by_country
    @city_list = Profile::CITY_LIST[params[:id].to_i]
    respond_to do |format|
      format.js { render :cities_by_country}
    end
  end
```

The js file to generate the option tags

```
#views/profiles/cities_by_country.js.erb
<%= options_for_select(@city_list) %>
```

The javascript to attach the "change" event on the country select tag:

```
# app/javascript/packs/country_cities.js
import Rails from '@rails/ujs';
var country_select, city_select, selected_country;
window.addEventListener("load", () => {
  country_select = document.querySelector("select#profile_country");
  city_select = document.querySelector("select#profile_city");
  country_select.addEventListener('change', (event) => {
    selected_country = country_select.selectedIndex;
    Rails.ajax({
      url: "/cities_by_country/" + selected_country,
      type: "get",
      data: "",
      success: function (data) {
        city_select.innerHTML = data;
       },
      error: function (data) { }
    })
  })
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Sorry to pile it on you but this is really broken.

Lets start with the controller/route. The idiomatic way to do this through a nested route - `GET /countries/:country_id/cities`. Nor should you really be shoehorning this into your Profile model / ProfilesController.

You can declare the route with:

```
get '/countries/:country_id/cities', to: 'countries/cities#index'
```

Or by using `resources` with a block:

```
resources :countries, only: [] do
  resources :cities, only: [:index], module: :countries
end
```

And the controller like so:

```
module Countries
  class CitiesController < ApplicationController
    # GET /countries/:country_id/cities
    def index
      @cities = Profile::CITY_LIST[params[:city_id].to_i] 
    end
  end
end
```

Not sure I can really get behind why you would want to use a constant in a model that should not be responsible for this at all instead of actually creating Country and City models.

The biggest issue with your JavaScript is that its completely non-idempotent. It all runs on `window.addEventListener("load")` so that it works on the intitial page load and then breaks down completely when Turbolinks replaces the page contents with AJAX since those event handlers were attached directly to the elements themselves.

To write JavaScript that works with Turbolinks you need to think differently. Create idempotent handlers that catch the event as it bubbles up the DOM.

```
# app/javascript/packs/country_cities.js
import Rails from '@rails/ujs';

document.addEventListener('change', (event) => {
  let input = event.target;
  if (input.matches('#profile_country')) {
    Rails.ajax({
      url: `/cities/${input.value}/country`,
      type: 'get',
      dataType : 'script'
    });
  }
});
```

If you want to use a `js.erb` template you also need to rewrite your view so that it transforms the page:

```
// app/views/countries/cities.js.erb
document.getElementById("#profile_city").innerHTML = "<%= j options_for_select(@cities) %>";
```

But you could also just use JSON and create the option elements on the client if you want to avoid making your server responsible for client side transformations.

Comment: **thanks** Let me study your points and I will have follow up questions. One thing though, the constant CITY_LIST and COUNTRY_LIST were there to simplify the example. My focus was on the javascript and ajax and "proper" use of ujs and not breaking turbolinks. Which it sounds like i did break. (p.s. you are not piling on, I appreciate that you gave you feedback)